# Change user for automatic login

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, automatic-logon

Windows-7 is configured to automatically login on boot.  I want to change which user it logins to.

more details
I have 3 accounts:

- Administator

  - administrator
  - no password
  - default for auto login
- Mine

  - administrator
  - password protected
  - I want this to be the default
- Other

  - standard user
  - no password
- Guest (disabled)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open up run and type in control userpasswords2

Choose the account you want to auto-login with and uncheck [users must enter a username and password to use this computer]

Click [Apply]
You should be prompted to enter in the username and password.

For more details, please see: http://www.w7forums.com/automatic-login-t420.html

Comment: I figured it out.  You didn't answer the question directly but your answer helped.  My problem was the checkbox was already unchecked.  I had to check it first then follow your instructions.

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest way.   ;-)  Download and run the SysInternal's "AutoLogon" program from...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905

Comment: What does he do after he downloads and runs this? Can you please elaborate on how this software can help, and how to use it to accomplish this task?