# How to remove Win10 login screen asking for username and password (showing despite netplwiz indicating it shouldn't be)?

Tags: windows-10, login

My laptop is running Win 10 Pro (64bit, v1903) and there is only one user, who has admin rights. When I open netplwiz, it shows "Users must enter a username and password to use this computer" as unchecked for this user.

Yet on boot I am getting a screen asking me to enter username and password. How can I remove this?

@Ramshound - this is a screenshot of what I get when I go `control userpasswords2`. (I've blanked out the username. It's the same in both instances - the single username I use for this machine.)

[image]

Comment: You have to toggle the checkbox on/off and back on again.  You will be given a prompt to provide the password.  If it’s a blank password, then just provide a blank password, be sure your user name is selected when you do this.  There is an existing question with an answer (answered this question specifically in the past) but I cannot find it right now

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/96767/change-user-for-automatic-login/96771#96771 and https://superuser.com/questions/495083/in-windows-8-how-do-you-disable-the-unlock-password-for-microsoft-accounts/502173#502173

Comment: Many thanks for this, but unfortunately this isn't working in Win10. Those other questions were for Win 7 and 8. In netplwiz I selected, checked, hit OK; selected, unchecked, hit OK, provided blank password. On restart, same problem.

Comment: I know it’s working because I have followed those instructions for on every Windows 10 machine I have. I will have to find my answer with a screenshot I suppose.

Comment: I can understand writing :-)

Comment: It’s not intuitive;  The UI makes you believe it’s enabled, but it’s not, until you get the password prompt.  That sets the default user, and despite what’s been reported elsewhere, you can set any user as the default user and have then automatically login after a reboot.  I for years had a blank password on Windows 10 and automatically logged into my single account machine

Comment: I've tried again now, doing a restart while the box was checked, before unchecking again and restarting a second time, but the problem is still there. This was caused by something I did recently after going ctrl-alt-del; I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: You are rebooting your machine?  Without knowing what you did difficult to diagnose your problem.  What I can tell you is those instructions still work on Windows 10

Comment: They're not working on my installation of Windows 10.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the window that gets displayed when you run `control userpasswords2`?  I just verified that it's still possible on the current version of Windows (this includes 1909) to automatically logged into a user account.

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: So do the following: 1) select the user name by clicking on it.  2) toggle the checkbox. 3) Once you toggle the checkbox off you will be given a prompt for your current password (blank password is fine). That should work.

Comment: Thanks @Ramshound for your efforts, but I have now tried exactly this and on restart I am still getting a screen saying "Other User" and asking for a username and password. Then I can get in by typing the username and hitting return, leaving the password blank, but I'd like to get straight in. I am interpreting "toggle the checkbox" as meaning select, check, "Apply", "OK", select, uncheck, "Apply", leave current password blank, "OK", "OK".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this problem by installing the Microsoft program [Autologon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon). This requires that the automatically logged-in account has a non-blank password, so I had to create one. It's now working fine.